# Hide Passive Unused Withheld Army

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I don't know what to call it, but in several past versions of Heroes, I could deselect certain armies before a battle.  When going into certain fights I may not want to bring out my priestesses or something, can I protect them this way in Heroes VI?

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve what you want you have to drag the desired unit and drop it outside of the Tactical grid. When clicking on Start battle the window should pop up saying if you truly want to start the  battle without all the troops.